# Annotation information missed after compiled with ECJ Compiler

Tags: eclipse, javac, ecj

I found the bytecode compiled from ECJ compiler has the annotation information missing.

The source code decompiled from bytecode compiled by javac:

```
public class HelloWorldApp {

    @GetAction("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

The source code decompiled from bytecode compiled by ECJ:

```
public class HelloWorldApp {

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

So clearly the annotation `@GetAction("/hello")` is missing from the bytecode compiled by ECJ (in memory compilation).

Anyone has encountered this issue before and get any clue?

**Update with more information**

Take a look at the following screenshot:
[image]

So it is in the `ASTNode.resolveAnnotations()` methods line #797:

A) The state `if ((method.tagBits & TagBits.AnnotationResolved) != 0) return annotations;` will return `null` as annotations even

B) the source annotation `@GetAction("/hello")` is presented because

C) the `this.annotations` field is `null` and

D) the if condition `(method.tagBits & TagBits.AnnotationResolved) != 0` evaluates to true

**Updates 2**

It looks like I captured the screen too early, so once process finished, I found the annotations information get stored:

[image]

However I still can't get the annotation information from the result file. Click [here](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/92L1lyG2/0/blob?download) to download the bytecode file generated:

[image]

**Note** I am using ECJ 4.4.1:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Just add the following lines:

```
    opt(map, OPTION_TargetPlatform, "1.6");
```

The issue is caused by default JDK version is 1.2 in ECJ, which does not support annotation